# Spurious Test Failures using Picasso and Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I just upgraded to Robolectric 2.1.1 and integrated Picasso today. I now have two test cases that fail randomly (one of these fragments doesn't even use Picasso). If I keep running the tests, everything usually ends up passing (might take a few tries).

**Test**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    detailActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity( ActivityUnderTest.class )
                                .withIntent( createIntent() )
                                .create()
                                .start()
                                .resume()
                                .get();

    // Note: The other test case doesn't use the fancy withIntent() doohickey
}

public static Intent createIntent()
{
    Bundle bundle = DetailFragment.createBundle( getTestData() );
    Intent intent = new Intent( new ActivityUnderTest(), Activity.class );
    intent.putExtras( bundle );
    return intent;
}

@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception
{
    assertNotNull( detailActivity );
}
```

**Codez**

I am sending in a bundle of information to the activity, which is basically an empty shell. The activity displays a Fragment via XML. In my Fragment, I get the data from the bundle using `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()`.

**Lying Warning**

[WARN] You're instantiating an activity (com.colabug.project.singlepanel.ActivityUnderTest) directly; consider using Robolectric.buildActivity() instead.

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An unexpected exception occurred
at com.squareup.picasso.Request$1.run(Request.java:114)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$PostedRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:162)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:107)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:92)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceToLastPostedRunnable(Scheduler.java:68)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:25)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:219)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:258)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.invokeWhilePaused(ActivityController.java:202)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.start(ActivityController.java:144)
at com.colabug.project.singlepanel.DetailActivityTest.setUp(DetailActivityTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Bitmap config was null.
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getBytesPerPixel(ShadowBitmap.java:338)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getRowBytes(ShadowBitmap.java:225)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowBitmap.getByteCount(ShadowBitmap.java:230)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.getByteCount(Bitmap.java)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$BitmapHoneycombMR1.getByteCount(Utils.java:250)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.getBitmapBytes(Utils.java:65)
at com.squareup.picasso.Stats.processBitmap(Stats.java:64)
at com.squareup.picasso.Stats.bitmapDecoded(Stats.java:40)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.loadFromType(Picasso.java:365)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.resolveRequest(Picasso.java:215)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.run(Picasso.java:197)
at com.squareup.picasso.Request.run(Request.java:108)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:244)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.colabug</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Project</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Make sure this is below the android dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
            <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- See http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ -->
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas? IntelliJ might be the cause since it shows up in the stacktrace. I have used `mvn clean` and manually cleaned up auto generated files on the command line and rebuilt the project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

Drew is correct. The NPE is occurring in a background thread.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Bitmap config was null.

Fundamentally this seems to be an issue with `ShadowBitmap`. However the solution I opted for was to create a `MockPicasso` class.

The stub implementation prevents the NPE. It also has the added benefit of preventing the unit tests from requesting bitmaps over the network in the first place.

**MockPicasso.java**

```
package com.squareup.picasso;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MockPicasso extends Picasso {
    private static String lastImagePath = null;
    private static ImageView lastTargetImageView = null;

    MockPicasso() {
        super(null, null, null, Cache.NONE, null, new MockStats());
    }

    public static void init() {
        singleton = new MockPicasso();
    }

    public static String getLastImagePath() {
        return lastImagePath;
    }

    public static ImageView getLastTargetImageView() {
        return lastTargetImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public RequestBuilder load(String path) {
        lastImagePath = path;
        return new MockRequestBuilder();
    }

    class MockRequestBuilder extends RequestBuilder {
        @Override
        public void into(ImageView target) {
            lastTargetImageView = target;
        }
    }

    static class MockStats extends Stats {
        MockStats() {
            super(Cache.NONE);
        }

        @Override
        void bitmapDecoded(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Using `getLastImagePath()` and `getLastTargetImageView()` you can test your code is requesting the correct image and loading it in the correct view without actually hitting the network.

**MyActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("avatar_url");
    Picasso.with(this).load(path).into(avatar);
}
```

**MyActivityTest.java**

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayAvatar() throws Exception {
    MockPicasso.init();
    String imageUrl = "http://www.example.com/test.jpg";
    Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra("avatar_url", imageUrl);
    MyActivity myActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class)
            .create().get();

    myActivity.setIntent(intent);
    Robolectric.shadowOf(myActivity).callOnCreate(null);
    ImageView avatar = (ImageView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    assertThat(MockPicasso.getLastImagePath()).isEqualTo(imageUrl);
    assertThat(MockPicasso.getLastTargetImageView()).isSameAs(avatar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info Chuck! Will check this out this weekend and see if it fixes my error.

Comment: Hope this helped. Here is a [blog post](https://engineering.aweber.com/unit-testing-remote-images-on-android-with-picasso-and-robolectric/) I wrote with more background info and a slightly more in-depth example.

Comment: @ecgreb: How do you make MockPicasso a part of the com.squareup.picasso package?

Comment: I just replicated the folder structure in my project and placed the file in `src/test/java/com/squareup/picasso/MockPicasso.java`.

Answer (score 1):

The warning isn't lying.

> Intent intent = new Intent( new ActivityUnderTest(), Activity.class );

The "new ActivityUnderTest()" qualifies as "instantiating an activity directly."

In many cases where tests fail/pass seeming-randomly, there is a threading issue in the underlying code.  The last time this happened to me the "sometimes this fails" test was actually exposing a race condition in my queue code.

I find that when I have the reaction "this test is stupid!" I almost discover that the test is actually smarter than me (and nicer than me, too, as it is trying to be helpful).

Comment: Ah, good catch. Glad I included the warning that I thought had no bearing. Will try tomorrow!